# Android Wear is collapsing group of 1 notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I have a small set of `Notification`s that are generated and shown on the Wearable device. They are pretty straightforward notifications, but I'm facing a problem with stacking.

I use [`setGroup(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) to ensure similar notifications are stacked. The problem is when there's only one notification: Its actions are not accessible unless it is tapped. As it's only one notification in the card stream, I would expect Wear to auto-expand it and allow me to reach for its actions with a simple swipe, but unfortunately I have to tap it before swiping.

Is it possible to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for without explicitly keeping track of which notifications are shown and using [`setGroup(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) dynamically? I had assumed this would work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the Android 5.0.1 update to Android Wear now properly handles this case!

Original reply:
Unfortunately, no - there is currently no special handling for groups of only one notification.

In almost all cases, you should be updating the [summary notification](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddSummary) when your group changes - at that same point you should have enough information to determine if you only have one notification (and hence, can just post a single notification like normal and forgo the summary notification/group) or multiple notifications (in which you should publish the summary notification and all of the grouped notifications).

Comment: What a bummer. Since these are generated only on the Wearable, the summary doesn't really make much sense (that's not how Wear stacks them). I guess I'll have to resort to do some manual management here. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, version 5.0.1 handles this gracefully. Hurray!

Comment: Woohoo! Glad they fixed it